# Socketio sending to individual socketid (private message)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've been trying to implement a chat service using socketio. I need to set a message to a selected socket id. The documentation says to use a function like    `socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');`
But it doesnt seem to be working. few moths ago i achieved this functionality by a function like `io.sockets.connected[<socketid>].emit('hey', 'I just met you');` but now it doesnt seem to work any more. Btw the `socket.broadcast.emit();` works pretty well. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manage to send private message by the following code.

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("online", data => {
    socket.name = data.username;
    onlineUsers.push(data);
    sockets[data.username] = socket.id;
  });
  socket.on("message", function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit("public", data);
  });

  socket.on("send_personal_message", function(data) {
    socket.to(sockets[data.user]).emit("personal", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", reason => {
    sockets.splice(sockets.findIndex(id => id === socket.id), 1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socket.broadcast.to(<socketid>)` to broadcast to specific socket id.

Here is an example:

```
socket.join('my-unique-room-name');
socket.broadcast.to('my-unique-room-name').emit('welcome', 'helloWorld'); //only people in 'my-unique-room-name' will receive this message
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this example is a little unclear, but it's a good way of creating private messages between two users. Rather than sending a loose message to a random socketID, the two users both join a private room with only two users allowed. Messages are sent to the entire room, but because there's only two people in the room, it's the same as a private conversation. Depends on what works best for the system you're building.